# 400 bad request when querying microsoft graph with http post

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-graph-api, http-post, bad-request, request-headers

I've been doing some testing with Microsoft Graph and I seem to have hit a brick wall; Wondering if anyone can give me a steer in the right direction.

The following code is from my test app (vb)...

```
 Imports System.Net
 Imports System.Text
 Imports System.IO
 Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
 
 
 Class MainWindow
 
     Public Shared graph_url As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/"
     Public Shared br As String = ControlChars.NewLine
 
     Dim myscope As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
     Dim mysecret As String = "zzx...BX-"
     Dim mytenantid As String = "7aa6d...d409199"
     Dim myclientid As String = "4e37...5a59"
     Dim myuri As String = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & mytenantid & "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
     Dim mytoken As String = ""
 
 
     Public Function HTTP_Post(ByVal url As String, ByVal postdata As String)
         Try
             Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
             Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
             postReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & mytoken)
             postReq.Method = "POST"
             postReq.PreAuthenticate = True
             Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
             If Not postdata = Nothing Then
                 Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postdata)
                 postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
             End If
             postreqstream.Close()
             request_header.Text = postReq.Headers.ToString
             Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
             Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
             Dim response As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
             Return (response)
         Catch ex As Exception
             user_results.Text = ex.Message.ToString
         End Try
     End Function
 
     Public Function GetNewToken()
         Console.WriteLine(myuri)
         Dim post_data As String = "client_id=" & myclientid & "&client_secret=" & mysecret & "&scope=" & myscope & "&grant_type=client_credentials"
         Dim token As String = HTTP_Post(myuri, post_data)
         get_result.Text = JObject.Parse(token).SelectToken("access_token")
         mytoken = JObject.Parse(token).SelectToken("access_token")
     End Function
 
     Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
         GetNewToken()
     End Sub
 
     Private Sub usrget_Copy_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles usrget_Copy.Click
         Dim url As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*{myUPN}*"
         Dim post_data As String = Nothing
         Dim return_data As String = HTTP_Post(url, post_data)
         req_url.Text = url
     End Sub
 End Class
```

The GetNewToken() function works fine and I retrive a valid token without an issue.

When i try and use that token to query a user, i get 400 Bad request - no additional info as such; just that.

I've examined the headers of my POST request and tried it several different ways, but cannot seem to overcome this; As far as i can tell my request is formatted as specified in the documentation for Microsoft Graph.

Have also googled the hell out of this to see if there was something obvious or simple I have overlooked; I've seen a few posts on this topic where people suggested setting the Authorization header before anything else - I tried that and it made no difference.
A few people also suggected setting the Accept to 'application/json'; I also tried that and it made no difference.

I've outputted some of the details to the gui and grabbed a screenshot so you can see what I'm seeing...
[image: Screengrab of test app gui]

Interestingly, If i try the 'Query users' before i grab a token, I get a 401 unauthorized which would suggest that the request itself is working correctly.

As i mentioned, this is a testing app whilst I get some functionality working (some data obscured for obvious reasons); I'm not concerned about the tidyness of code or anything like that at this point.

If anyone is able to help it would be very much appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Per the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) you should be submitting a GET request and not a POST request. I'm not sure why it isn't returning a 405, because it probably should be.

Comment: please provide correlation id and timestamp of error message

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Comment: @David was spot on - it had to be a GET, not a post :)